# Does installing from source stop apt-get updates?

Tags: apache2, 18.04, security, repository

The current version of Apache for Ubuntu 18.0.4 is Apache 2.4.29 which is vulnerable to CVE-2018-1302. And since we are doing this under a [PCI site](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/), I need to get the vulnerability fixed ASAP.

I am considering building from source. But the issue is, I do not want to be stuck on the version built from source. So my question is, if I build from Apache 2.4.33 (which fixes the vulnerability), will apt-get update to a newer version once available? Is there anyway to tell when the official version from repo is expected to be released? I have been watching [this site](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2018/CVE-2018-1302.html), but it does not give a ton of detail.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is classified as "Low risk".

Comment: You can build from source and monitor the site you mentioned till a fixed is released. Then you can return to normal operation through apt.

Comment: @MatsK Doesn't matter. Auditor says it is a fail and he is the one that signs the line, not me.  Trust me.. I agree with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

APT only see what is in the APT database.

If you install from source APT will not be aware of that and it will NOT be upgraded via APT!

Comment: Just to clarify, installing from source is not a problem, but remove the Apache installed via APT first so you don't have conflicts.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure if I will go down this route though. Considering it will complicate things down the road when it comes to updates, plus I got to thinking I would also have to build each dependency Apache module as well. I suppose I will just hope and wait for an official release. I just wish I had some kind of a timeline or more a a way to view progress.